# Packaging mp3 files into Qt app

Tags: macos, qt, installation, mp3, qmediaplayer

Since I found mp3 files can't be retrieved by QMediaPlayer from resource, I figure it out to use them as local file. I use [this cmd](http://dragly.org/2013/11/05/copying-data-files-to-the-build-directory-when-working-with-qmake/) with a little modification to copy files into installation directory:

```
copydata.commands = $(COPY_DIR) $$PWD/resources/sound $$OUT_PWD/HomeControl.app/Contents/MacOS
first.depends = $(first) copydata
export(first.depends)
export(copydata.commands)
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += first copydata
```

So those files existed in the /HomeControl.app/Contents/MacOS/sound. From Qt Creator the app plays the mp3 perfectly, but if executed from the build directory it doesn't play the mp3 at all! Really don't know why.

```
arm away btn clicked
current media:  "file:///Dev/Qt_Sample/build-test_widgets-Desktop_Qt_5_3_0_clang_64bit-Debug/HomeControl.app/Contents/MacOS/sound/System_Arm_Away.mp3"
disarm stay btn clicked
current media:  "file:///Dev/Qt_Sample/build-test_widgets-Desktop_Qt_5_3_0_clang_64bit-Debug/HomeControl.app/Contents/MacOS/sound/System_Disarmed.mp3"
```

Is there any difference from executing in the Qt creator & directly from the App? Like debug mode or what?

Or is there other ways to correctly deploy mp3 files into the bundle?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I build in resources for OS X bundles:

```
mac {
    Resources.files = dirInTheProjectDirectory
    Resources.path = Contents/MacOS
    QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += Resources
}
```

You can call Resources whatever you fancy.

That copies them to `Contents/MacOS/dirInTheProjectDirectory`. You can then access them with `QDir(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()+"/dirInTheProjectDirectory/");`

The likely problem is when you're accessing them in your code you're pointing to the path in the build directory, and not the path that's within your bundle.

Comment: Thanks @nicholas-smith. 
Follow your script I copy the mp3 files under PROJECT_ROOT/resources/sound into Contents/MacOS/sound.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final solution. Thank you @nicholas-smith.

In the .pro file:

```
# deploy with mp3 folder
mac {
    Resources.files = ./resources/sound
    Resources.path = Contents/MacOS
    QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += Resources
}
```

Then accessing those file with:

```
// pass the path of mp3 to the QMediaPlayer
playAudio(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()
    + "/sound/System_Disarmed.mp3");
```

From log it shows:

```
arm away btn clicked
current media:  "file:///Dev/Qt_Sample/build-test_widgets-Desktop_Qt_5_3_0_clang_64bit-Debug/HomeControl.app/Contents/MacOS/sound/System_Arm_Away.mp3"
```